# How to break and return in a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, return, break

I try to access a value in an array of dictionary. The dataArray looks like this:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
}

let person1: Person  = Person(name: "Steven", lastName: "miller", age: 23)
let person2: Person = Person(name: "jana", lastName: "drexler", age: 31)
let person3: Person = Person(name: "hanna", lastName: "montana", age: 56)

var dataArray = [Person]()

dataArray.append(person1)
dataArray.append(person2)
dataArray.append(person3)
```

Now I want to access the age of jana. If I´m doing this:

```
func getAge() ->Int {

    var age: Int = 0

    for items in dataArray {
        while items.name == "jana" {
            age = items.age

            return age

            break       // This break will never be executed because of return.
        }
        break           // setting the break here, the loop will break after first round
    }
    return age
}
```

the loop will stop after the first round. (it works only for steven, because he is in the first round of the lopp.) The array is quite long, so i need to stop the loop after the first match. Setting break after return, it will not be executed because of return. Setting return after break, it´s the same. Any suggestions?

For vadian:

```
class AGE {

    func getAge() -> Int? {

    dataArray.append(person1)
    dataArray.append(person2)
    dataArray.append(person3)

    // Cannot call value of non-function type `Person`
    return dataArray.first(where: { $0.name == "john" }?.age

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use my code in your previous question? Now as the method is not static anymore, the code is supposed to work. These kind of repeat loops are not necessary in Swift. Use `filter` or `first(where:` or `index(of`

Comment: Why do you use a `while` loop inside the `for` loop? Use `if` instead of `while`. Why is there a `break` after the `while` loop? You only check the first element of the array.

Comment: I would very much like to use you code. But it doesn´t work.

Comment: What does not work? And your code is (again) inconsistent.

Comment: @ vadian:  "Cannot call value of non function type Person"

Comment: In which line ? In a class / struct or in a Playground?

Comment: @ vadian: just in a file. no playground no class/struct. After `dataArray.append(person3)`

Comment: @ vadian: I just added the code for you. Still iinterested, because it looks very effective.

Comment: @JoschHazard Looks like you're missing a parenthesis? I think it should be `return dataArray.first(where: { $0.name == "jana" })?.age`.

Comment: As smarx already stated there's a closing parenthesis missing right before the question mark..

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error. Could it be that this method is meant for dictionaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable used before being initialized. Am I stupid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604743/variable-used-before-being-initialized-am-i-stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? No need for the inner loop (which was never looping anyway).

```
func getAge() ->Int {
    for item in dataArray {
        if item.firstName == "jana" {
            return item.age
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

As a side note, a dictionary might be a better way to store the data to make lookups more efficient.

Comment: I don´t really understand. In this case, does the loop stop after it hits jana? My real Array is much longer.

Comment: Yes, as soon as the `return` happens, the loop (and entire function) is over.

Comment: Awesome. I was thinking too complicated. Now the knot in my brain is dissolved.

Comment: Had to give rmaddy the acceptance, because he was first. But thanks to you too, was very helpfull. Will check dictionary how it could be an option.

Comment: I don't particularly care, but I'm pretty sure my answer was first. (2017-06-17 19:22:02Z vs. 2017-06-17 19:24:38Z)

Comment: Generally it's considered a bad practice to return inside a loop. This is because as you read a large code it's not clear all the situations when a function steps out and return if there are return statements all scattered across the code.

Comment: @derloopkat Although I have heard that before, I think it's far from "generally [being] considered a bad practice." Certainly for a short function, I'm of the opinion that an early return is better than the alternatives. (In this case, though, `.first` is even clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `while` loop or the `break` statements.

If you want to iterate the loop looking for the age of a specific person, all you need is:

```
func getAge() -> Int? {
    for items in dataArray {
        if items.name == "jana" {
            return items.age
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note the updated return value to be an optional. A `nil` return value means the person wasn't found. Don't use `0` as a magic value.

It's also bad to hardcode the name. Pass it as a parameter. And use better variable names:

```
func getAge(of name: String) -> Int? {
    for person in dataArray {
        if person.name == name {
            return person.age
        }
    }
    return nil
}

if let age = getAge(of: "jana") {
    print("age is \(age)")
} else {
    print("Name not found")
}
```

Comment: Ok,  I think I got it. The return person.age will stop the loop at the point the match was found right? Even if the array has thousands of entries, it will not move on after the match, right? perfect.

Comment: `return` means just that - return and now. No other code will be executed in the method after `return`.

Comment: now I realise, my initial question was kind of silly.

Comment: Ok, so I had to give `smarx` the acceptance because he was first. Thanks to you both. Helped me a lot!

Comment: @JoschHazard You can accept any answer you wish but don't base it on who was first. Base it on the answer that best answers your question. Someone might come by a week from now and post a really good answer and it would be fine to accept that answer.

Comment: @ rmaddy true true, but in this case, the essence of the solution was answered from you both. Because of that i wouldn´t judge which answer was better. So I wanted to come back on who was first.