# Does Swift allow declaring a variable without an initial value?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, initialization

I thought I knew how to declare variables until I just saw this example.

In the example a constant is declared.

```
let timeOfDay: String
```

I thought you could not declare a variable/constant without initializing it unless you declared it as an Optional?

Of course the program bombs when I go to print the constant.  How is it the compiler allowed this?  I entered this into a Playground.

A full example:

```
let hourOfDay = 12
let timeOfDay: String
if hourOfDay < 6 {
    timeOfDay = "Early morning"
} else if hourOfDay < 12 {
    timeOfDay = "Morning"
} else if hourOfDay < 17 {
    timeOfDay = "Afternoon"
} else if hourOfDay < 20 {
    timeOfDay = "Evening"
} else if hourOfDay < 24 {
    timeOfDay = "Late evening"
} else {
    timeOfDay = "INVALID HOUR!"
}
print(timeOfDay)
```

Comment: Let's see the rest of the class, or struct, or function, or whatever, where `timeOfDay` is declared.

Comment: Just added it.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Related (not a dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604743/

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is smart enough to figure out that on every possible code path that leads to the first read access of `timeOfDay`, it is in fact initialized exactly once. Try leaving out one of the assignments as an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler let's you declare a let variable without value, but it expects you to set a value for it later. It's possible to not enter on any of the `if` statements in your example, so the compiler knows that you're trying to read a value that may not exists. You can try a simple `if` `else` statement and try to run, just to check :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can declare a Constant without an initial value in Swift. But we need to assign a value later so we can use that Constant, otherwise there would be a compile error. It is also important to note that while we can change the value multiple times in Variables, we can assign a value to a Constant only ONCE.

In the given example above, the if-else statements can only assign a value to the Constant timeOfDay only once. After that, we cannot assign a new value or even create a new if-else statements to change the value of timeOfDay anymore.